# How to attach media files to a post programmatically in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, if a media file is uploaded within the WP admin post edit screen, it will automatically be attached to the current post being edited. However, I'm allowing my site's authors to upload images via the front-end. The upload form I have created is on the post page (within the loop) so I have the post's ID available when uploading the image.

Is there a way to automatically attach the uploaded image to the post? Currently when I visit the *Media* section in WP admin, all of the images uploaded thus far are marked as 'unattached'.

Ref:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments#Attachment_to_a_Post

**Edit:** I should mention I'm using WordPress Liveblog: https://github.com/Automattic/liveblog - images are uploaded when a user pastes an image URL into the form.

Answer (score 7):

You can run following function after your upload form submission. Let say your upload form is as following:

```
<form action="your_action.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="attachment" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php global $post; echo $post->ID; ?>" />
</form>
```

And in your upload handling part:

```
<?php

$filename = $_FILES["file"]["attachment"];

$post_id = $_POST["post_id"];

$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);


$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attach_data );
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I should have mentioned I'm using WordPress Liveblog: https://github.com/Automattic/liveblog - images are uploaded when a user pastes an image URL into the form textarea and submits the form. I've edited my question

Comment: How does Liveblog insert the image into the media library? If I knew this I could try to apply your solution

Comment: I am analyzing liveblog .  I will provide solution as I found the exact way

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can tell, Plupload is used to do the uploading. A user has to enter the image URL and hit submit. Images seem to be uploaded to the WordPress /uploads/ folder and the image is listed in the Media manager in WP admin. However, each image is marked as 'unattached'

Comment: I think I've worked it out. In liveblog.php, `add_default_plupload_settings()` sets up some default Plupload settings. `post_id` needed to be set up here so that it is available to `media_handle_upload()` later along the line. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have also analyzed that but there is no option for post id in `add_default_plupload_settings`

Comment: Quite true! my solution involves editing the plugin file. You have to add `post_id` to the `multipart_params` array. globalise `$post` then `$post->ID` will get you the post's ID.

Comment: IMO `$filename = $_FILES["file"]["attachment"];` should have been `$filename = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];`